# how to sort subarray in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

i need to sort the following ,any ideas are appreciated:

```
a=[
    ["****************1************","20120210 08:04:05,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Receive message "<FIXML>","\n"],
    ["****************3************","20120210 08:04:00,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Sent message "<FIXML>","\n"],
    ["****************2************","20120210 08:03:05,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Allocated message "<FIXML>","\n"],
]
```

how to sort this array  either by time or by steps 1,2,3-usual a.sort{|x,y| x<=>y} not working here

Comment: "by either time or by steps" does not make sense (consider expanding the explanation and/or input+results). Also, `sort {|x,y| x <=> y}` is better written as `sort`. However, I imagine you want to do something such as `sort {|x,y| x[1] <=> y[1]}` or use `sort_by {|e| e[1]}`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to sort by two criteria, do

```
a.sort_by do |item|
  time = parse_time_from_string(item[1])
  step = parse_step_from_string(item[0])
  [time, step]
end
```

Comment: a.sort_by {|e| e[1]} --Great, worked,the rest didn't produce the right results           `****************1************
20120210 08:04:05,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Receive message <FIXML>

****************2************
20120210 08:03:05,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Allocated message <FIXML>

****************4************
20120210 08:04:00,404 DEBUG MQReceiver - Sent message <FIXML>`

Comment: thanks a lot -it took me 2 months top sort something like this